# Use gnome-keyring as ssh agent instead of openssh

Tags: 16.04, kde, gnome-keyring, ssh-agent

I want to use `gnome-keyring` in KDE to provide access to ssh passphrases. It is unlocked properly on login and the ssh agent socket is there. My problem is that the `openSSH ssh-agent` shadows this. Apparently the KDE session is started with `ssh-agent`

```
$ ps aux | grep ssh-agent
beaujean  2029  0.0  0.0  11140   316 ?        Ss   11:22   0:00 /usr/bin/ssh-agent /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-session /usr/bin/im-launch /usr/bin/startkde
```

Then in the kde session,

```
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-Jv2eneUNSlQ6/agent.3739;
```

the ssh-agent is empty, and I'm prompted for my password. Incidentally, the gnome-keyring ssh socket is active, too

```
$ ss -xl | grep ssh
u_str  LISTEN     0      128    /run/user/1000/keyring/ssh 25108       * 0
u_str  LISTEN     0      128    /tmp/ssh-Jv2eneUNSlQ6/agent.3739 36471      * 0
```

I can manually switch the socket

```
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=`ss -xl | grep -o '/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh'`
```

and access to the ssh key w/o password works in this shell. How do I achieve this for the entire KDE session on startup? There are several questions around on how to achieve the opposite; i.e., prevent `gnome-keyring` from overwriting the ssh-agent. For me, it unfortunately doesn't overwrite `SSH_AUTH_SOCK`. Perhaps if I could avoid kde being started by `ssh-agent`, things would be fine but I don't know at what point of the start-up process this command

```
/usr/bin/ssh-agent /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-session /usr/bin/im-launch /usr/bin/startkde
```

is executed

Answer (score 3):

I didn't really find a solution, others had the same question on the [KDE forum](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=128511) but a simple workaround is to set the ssh agent in `.profile`

```
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=`ss -xl | grep -o '/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh'`
```

this is not overwritten by the rest of the start-up procedures and at least sets it correctly in a (startup) shell. In the rest of window system, it's still the other ssh agent, unfortunately.